# SPRESENSE突然死？

Tags: spresense

短いマイクロUSBデータケーブルから長いものに換えたとたんSPRESENSEの青いLEDが光らず、装着していたB-stem PDA01も機能しなくなりました。要するに電源が入らない状況のように見えます。元の短いマイクロUSBケーブルに戻しても状況は改善せず。それまでプログラミングもテストも順調であったのに。何が原因でしょうか？突然死することってありますか？

Comment: ケーブルを別の機器に挿して利用できるか確認するのも、問題点を切り分ける一つの方法かと思います。

Comment: 無論、そのケーブルは別の機器に挿してデータ通信できます。他の同一仕様のケーブルでも試しました。

Comment: とりあえず、USBも反応し、teratermなどではシリアルポートをオープンできるように見えますが、それ以上何もできません。

Answer (score 0):

ハードウェア観点からみると、シリアルポートが生きていて、電源LEDが点かない症状は、IC6のUSB-UARTブリッジのCP2102nが生きていて、5V->4Vを生成するIC5のLDO RP115L401D が死んでいる状態だと思います。

回路図はここで見れます。
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_design_ja.html

ICのデータシートを見ると、両方とも耐圧（最大定格電圧）は 6V 程度ですので、長いUSBケーブルを使用したときの電源が7Vかそれ以上の（12Vとか？）電圧になっており、これらのICにダメージを与えたのではないのかと想像します。

USBケーブルそのものは電源をそのままつなげているだけですので、USBケーブルに原因があるとは考えづらく、その先の電源に何か問題はないか見たほうがいいかも知れません。

かくいう私も一度、自作USBケーブルで12Vを間違って突っ込んで一枚ダメにしたことがあります。（泣）

Comment: 長いUSBケーブルは危険なんですね。PCから接続した状態でしたが、そういうこともあるのかと驚いています。

Comment: なるほど、PCからなんですね。あくまで想像でしかないですのが、お使いのPCのUSB の口はUSB  Type-C 対応ではないでしょうか？それがUSB-PD(Power Delivery)対応だと20Vまで供給できます。考えにくいことですが、長いUSBケーブルを使ったときにPCがSpresenseをUSB-PD機器と誤認識して20Vを供給してしまった可能性があります。ここはUSB-PD対応機器の知見がある方にアドバイスをいただきたいところです。（私のPCもUSB-PD対応の口があるので注意したいと思います…）

Comment: いえ、Type-Bです。

Comment: 表現が悪かったかも知れません。PC側の端子はUSB3.1以上ですか？

Comment: そのはずですが、3.1以上で機能しているかどうかわかりません。

Comment: 少し調べてみたのですが、PCとの接続でこのようなことが起きるとは考えにくいですね。USBアダプタの一部は、PDネゴシエーション前に20Vが出力されるものもあるようです。　https://www.macnica.co.jp/business/semiconductor/articles/texas_instruments/129277/ PC接続以外に、USBアダプタに接続したことはないでしょうか？（しかし、こんなUSBアダプタがあるなんて恐ろしいですね。Type-C対応のスマホに付属しているUSBアダプタは、電子工作ユーザーにとって危険かもしれません）